# Ubuntu 20.04 Full Disk Encryption - Wrong Password

Tags: boot, 20.04, password, encryption

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 with full disk encryption (initially upgraded from 18.04).

Decided I wanted to do a fresh install because I was having a few apps crashing and whatnot. But I'm getting this error when I know the password is correct after the reinstall of Ubuntu 20.04: `cryptsetup: ERROR: sda3_crypt: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?`

Here's the process I went through:

1. Created a USB with the Ubuntu 20.04 installation media on.
2. Booted from the USB and did a full wipe / reinstall, using the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option, making sure to tick the advanced options for "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation" and "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security"
3. Rebooted, removing the installation media USB as instructed.
4. When prompted for the encryption password I typed it in correctly but got the following error:

> cryptsetup: ERROR: sda3_crypt: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?

**Things which work**

- I can boot from the live USB and double click on the encrypted drive, a GUI appears asking for the password. When I enter the password, it unlocks the drive successfully and I can access the files.
- If I reboot again while the USB installation media is still in and get to the sda3_crypt password prompt, I can enter the very same password and it lets me into the OS.
- When I remove the drive and reboot again, it gives the same "bad password or options" error.

So -  it *looks* like there's some sort of encryption key tied to the installation media? So I HAVE to have that plugged in to be able to decrypt the OS. This is not the normal use case, right?

Previously I didn't have to have any USB plugged in (before reformatting), I'd just start up my laptop, enter the password, and it would go straight into the OS.

Any ideas how I can resolve this? Happy to reformat again, there's no data I'm worried about losing, the ENTIRE thing can be wiped and started from scratch.

Comment: Maybe a keyboard layout issue?

Comment: Would a USB stick being plugged in change the keyboard layout, though? :/